# Why isn't the automatic duplicate flag message capitalized?

Tags: feature-request

When you flag a question as a duplicate of another you automatically append the following comment:

> possible duplicate of {title of original question}

Shouldn't this sentence be capitalized properly? And perhaps even end with punctuation?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Perhaps the question is worth discussing again as the original question was asked a rough 4 years ago and a lot has changed in how the site addresses users since then?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth discussing again, but I'm afraid it would be declined for the same reason.

Comment: It's not actually a sentence.  Maybe that's why, for four years, SE has resisted putting a capital letter on it.  As Jeff Atwood points out (in his [wildly unpopular answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47209/102937)), there are many things that are not capitalized.  I think they think it's chic.

Comment: The [last time this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203566/when-flagging-duplicates-the-auto-posted-comment-should-be-capitalized-correctl) was posted wasn't 4 years ago... because it's a fragment SE refuses to sentence case it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it seems this question has no value other than perhaps to serve as a reference to other people searching the issue on this meta site.